# How to identify the longer user-input word/string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to create a small program for my homework and so far I made a GUI using Tkinter but I have trouble creating code that can make the program identify a long word.

How do I make the program understand and identify a long word/string?

This is my code so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkm

def show_name():
    string = entry1.get()
    tkm.showinfo('Longer String', string)

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('300x300')

label1 = tk.Label(window, text='String 1')
label1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry(window)
entry1.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(window, text='string 2')
label2.pack()

entry2 = tk.Entry(window)
entry2.pack()

label3 = tk.Label(window, text='string 3')
label3.pack()

entry3 = tk.Entry(window)
entry3.pack()

button2 = tk.Button(window, text='Identify longer string', command=show_name)
button2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you would consider a long string, but this example should show you.

```
maxlength = 10
string = 'the year is 2020 and it is december'
if len(string) > maxlength:
    print('This is a long string')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to find longest word. I added somethings to your code

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkm

#We get all values and ve sort this values as length and find the largest word.
def show_name(entry1, entry2, entry3):
    result = sorted([entry1, entry2, entry3], key=len)
    tkm.showinfo('Longer String', result[2])

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('300x300')

label1 = tk.Label(window, text='String 1')
label1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry(window)
entry1.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(window, text='string 2')
label2.pack()

entry2 = tk.Entry(window)
entry2.pack()

label3 = tk.Label(window, text='string 3')
label3.pack()

entry3 = tk.Entry(window)
entry3.pack()


                                                            # Use there lambda because we don't want to start this function untill we click it and we send entry values in this function.
button2 = tk.Button(window, text='Identify longer string', command=lambda: show_name(entry1.get(), entry2.get(), entry3.get()))
button2.pack()



window.mainloop()
```